# Retrieve the difference between Strings on BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

Is it possible to retrieve the difference between 2 strings using Bigquery functions.

Example.

**String 1: "Hello world"**

**String 2: "Hello big world"**

**Result expepected: "big"**

Thanks

Comment: can you provide few more involved examples to better illustrate the logic you want to apply

Comment: Hello. `REGEX_CONTAINS` will be true if a missing word is not a standalone word.
For example -> str_1 = "I like bigdata", str_2 = "I like big animals"
The current `WHERE` clause gives only "animals" as the difference while the actual differences could be "animals" and "big". So, please provide more examples to clarify your use case.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
with sample_data as (
    select 'hello world' as str_1, 'hello big world' as str_2
)

select 
    str_1
    , str_2_split
from sample_data 
, unnest(split(str_2, " ")) str_2_split
where regexp_contains(str_1, str_2_split)=false
```

this approach splits the second string into an array and compares it against the values in string_1.